# How to enable code completation on jupyter?

Tags: jupyter

I'm experiencing a very strange problem.
The code completetion is not working on my jupyter.
I have installed it at least 3 times, two manually and the last one via Anaconda.
I tried to use it on Chrome and Edge with no sucess.
I'm using it on Windows 10

Here goes the startup messages

```
[W 09:48:06.701 LabApp] Error loading server extension jupyter_nbextensions_configurator
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1942, in init_server_extensions
        mod = importlib.import_module(modulename)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_nbextensions_configurator'
[W 09:48:06.704 LabApp] Error loading server extension jupyter_tabnine
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1942, in init_server_extensions
        mod = importlib.import_module(modulename)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_tabnine'
[I 09:48:07.134 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from C:\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 09:48:07.135 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\Anaconda3\envs\tf\share\jupyter\lab
[I 09:48:07.142 LabApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: D:\Dev\Bolsa\src
[I 09:48:07.142 LabApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.1.4 is running at:
[I 09:48:07.143 LabApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=315a13e878a473d4f11f55f0d623240071060f151731429d
[I 09:48:07.144 LabApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=315a13e878a473d4f11f55f0d623240071060f151731429d
[I 09:48:07.145 LabApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 09:48:07.284 LabApp]
```

As you can see it is trying to load tabnine and jupyter_nbextensions_configurator, I'd installed it on the first jupyter installation, and I don't know why after two new jupyter installations and uninstall both of them jupyter still trying to load it.

Does anyone have any idea of what is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a solution for this problem, but I found a workaround.
I'd install the Python extension on VScode and then I'd open the jupyter notebook in there. So the code completation is working like a charm.

Here goes the instructions to open jupyter notebook on VSCode
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support